# Create an object of a class from another package with package name

Tags: java, android, oop

I am new to Java. I have the following package structure.

Package 1

- AppName

  - Main
  - SomeOtherClass

Package 2

- API

  - Load
  - Callback

From the Main class of AppName Package I want to create an object of Load class of the API package.

Now I can easily do that by `import API.*` and then using `new Load();`.

But what I want the full connotation of the Load class. I want to make a new API call using `new API.Load();`

So What I want is to be able to use `API.` prefix with Load class's construction. Is it possible at all? What kind of import will work? Simply using `new API.Load();` doesn't work. Android studio doesn't recognize the API keyword.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Ok I sort of have what I want. `com.achshar.testapp.API` is the complete name. So 
`new com.achshar.testapp.API.Load();` works fine. Now how can I make it `new API.Load();`?

Comment: Is API the root? Or is it part of another package?

Comment: `import API.*; new Load();` should be equivalent to `new API.Load();` (besides the fact that the import will import more than just Load).

Comment: I believe API is a sub-package of the main android package.

Comment: To me it sounds like you made another mistake there somewhere, sorry. What is the full, qualified name of the Load class?

Comment: com.achshar.testapp.API.Load is the full qualified name.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Ok I sort of have what I want. `com.achshar.testapp.API` is the complete name. So `new com.achshar.testapp.API.Load();` works fine. Now how can I make it `new API.Load();`?

Comment: You can only import classes, not packages. So that's not possible. Either you import it or you use the fully qualified name. You can only write new API.Load() if Load is in the package API (and not x.API or x.y.API, etc.)

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz huh alrighy, thanks then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a doubt, you can use `Class#getCanonicalName` to print the full path of a class.

Here, an example with `ArrayList`

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(str.getClass().getCanonicalName()); // java.util.ArrayList
```

And now if I want I can write my lists like the following

```
java.util.List<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Ok I sort of have what I want. `com.achshar.testapp.API` is the complete name. So `new com.achshar.testapp.API.Load();` works fine. Any idea how can I make it `new API.Load();` now?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. API still comes out as unresolved symbol.

Comment: @Achshar There is no way to make it possible. What you could do, is create your own `API` package at the root and put the class in it.

Comment: It's already my own package that I created. And the Load class is in the API package. It's a sub-package of the main testapp.

Comment: @Achshar You'll have to create it at the root of the application, not in another package... It should not be a subpackage

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense. But is it considered a bad practice to make a new root package? Any other caveats I should know about creating a root package instead of a sub package?

Comment: @Achshar I do not think it is considered bad practice. But calling a class by its full package name reduce the readability...

Comment: Yeah I guess it does but in this case the Load class is a little too ambiguous. which is why I wanted to put that and any other api related classes and interfaces in a package. Having `new Load()` scattered throughout the app makes less sense than `new api.load();` I think a new root level package is what I will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your API (some what like Proxy layer). In it you can create your Load.java class, Callback.Java class. Provide some different name to your package. 
If classes in API package of package 2 are not declared as final and also have public constructors, you can extend each class to create a new class in your created new API package. 
In the new class you create, you can override the methods (functions) and give your behavior. You can use super.methodOfAPI to get the behavior provided by the parent class and then can write your code to add the behavior you want.

You need to take care as when you wish to use original API package classes and when from your created layer. Use your imports accordingly.  Another way out is to append some common word like 'Proxy' in the end of the classes you creae in the new API package you create, it will resolve the conflicts.